# How i can return all strings before character using PHP

Tags: php, jquery

```
$string = 'pic.jpeg,pic_2.jpeg,pic_3.jpeg,';
```

How i can return only strings before the character for example like this:
Result:

```
<input type="text" value="pic.jpeg" />
<input type="text" value="pic_2.jpeg" />
<input type="text" value="pic_3.jpeg" />
```

This code only return first string (how i can use while here?)

```
$arr = explode(",", $string, 2);
echo $first = $arr[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = explode(",", $string);
foreach($arr as $val){
    echo $val;
}
```

Your original code has a limit on `explode` which I've removed.

Answer (score 1):

Dont use a limit in the explode.Also check for value is empty in looping as in your case you will get a empty element in the last position of your array after exploding

```
$string = 'pic.jpeg,pic_2.jpeg,pic_3.jpeg,';
$arr = explode(",", $string);
foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
 if(trim($val) != ''){
   echo '<input type="text" value="'.$val.'" />';
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through each element in the array and echo its text. Check the code below

```
$arr = explode(",", $string, 2);
foreach ($arr as &$value) {
    echo '<input type="text" value="$value" />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a comma on your last so you need to trim that before **`explode`**

```
<?php
$string = 'pic.jpeg,pic_2.jpeg,pic_3.jpeg,';
$string=rtrim($string,',');

$arr = explode(",",$string);
foreach($arr as $k=>$v)
{
echo "<input type='text' value=$v />";
}
```